# Parsing error: Unexpected token in below code of in Lightining controller

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript-controller

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set(v.columns[
               {label: 'Department ID', fieldName: 'DepartmentID', type: 'Auto Number'},
               {label: 'Department Name', fieldName: 'Name', type: 'text'},
               {label: 'Department Manager', fieldName: 'DepartmentManager', type: 'text'},
               {label: 'Employee Count', fieldName: 'NoofEmployee', type: 'number'}
        ]);
        var action= component.get("c.getRecord");
        action.setCallback(this, funtion(response){
                          var state=response.getState();
        if(state==="SUCCESS"){
            component.set("v.dept",response.getReturnValue());
        }
        else{
            console.log("Failed with state: " + state);
        }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);    
}
})
```

Comment: I am getting Parsing error: Unexpected token { at line 10 (i.e.  action.setCallback(this, funtion(response){ )
Can someone suggest me the what is require in this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On top of what [@sfdcfox has mentioned](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/239390/54851), your issue is on this line:

```
 action.setCallback(this, funtion(response){
```

You are missing a **c** in the word ***function***. You need to have it as:

```
 action.setCallback(this, function(response) {....});
```

Comment: +1 Good catch; I didn't copy-paste into a syntax highlighter, so I missed that one.

Comment: Very easy to miss for sure. I actually copied the snippet and was trying in dev console and was able to find it out on process of elimination only after I copy pasted another snippet on that line to be able to pin-point :). Interestingly, `component.set` as in its current form in the question just saves fine.

Comment: trying on dev console, +1 for this effort

Comment: @PranayJaiswal - that's the only separate chrome window that is always open on my workstation :P

Answer (score 2):

The compiler usually tells you what line the error is on, but it happens you have some typos on line 3; it's likely they weren't detected until everything got out of sync several lines later in this case.

The function signature should be:

```
component.set(string, object);
```

But you've written:

```
    component.set(v.columns[
```

This is simply invalid syntax in the long run.

The corrected version is:

```
    component.set("v.columns", [
```

Where the first parameter is almost always a string (rarely, a parameter when called from another function), and the missing comma is necessary to split the first and second parameter.